# How do you enable animation on a view's direct layer?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-animation, calayer

When I change the background color of a view's layer it changes instantly and doesn't animate like a sublayer would. What disables this?

```
class MyView: UIView {

    var mySublayer = CALayer()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        layer.addSublayer(mySublayer)
        mySublayer.frame = bounds
    }
}

let view = MyView()

view.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor // this changes the background color instantly

view.mySublayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor // this animates to the new color
```

So what is causing the view's direct layer to not animate it's background color to the new color?

Comment: How did you change the background?

Comment: you can use UIView.animation.

Comment: @willthatbeall : Take a look at the much elaborated answer to your question in edit. I have explained issues in your code and how to animate the change in the value of view's property

Comment: @Mohammadalijf view.layer.backgroundColor = someColor

Comment: thank you @SandeepBhandari I have fixed issue 1 and you provide a solution in issue 2. My question is if both the view's main layer and the sublayer I have added are both layers, why does the added sublayer animate to the new value just by changing it and the view's main layer doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the background color of your ViewController's view with animation block using

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 10) {
        self.view.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        //or you can use
        //self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green 
    }
```

Read [Animations](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html) to find the animatable properties of the View.

In iOS all the views are layer backed hence you can always change the properties of layer and it will impact the view associated with it.

**EDIT 1:**

Even after providing the answer above OP still seems to confused, so adding little more info to make it more understandable.

There seems to be couple of issues in your code.

**Issue 1:**

```
var mySublayer = CALayer()
```

Creates a `CALayer` of frame (0,0,0,0). You need to set the CALyer's frame. Though I don't understand what are you trying to do with mySublayer but in its current state its of no use. Animating the background color of `mySublayer` will not help you in anyway because its frame is (0,0,0,0)

Where is the best place to set its frame you ask! you can use

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.someLayer.frame = self.frame
}
```

**Issue 2:**

```
view.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
```

The statement above will not animate the change in the value of layer's background color property. I have shown it in answer above, that you will have to use `UIView.animate` to animate the change in the value of view's property else you can make use of Core animation APIs like `CABasicAnimation`.

Simply setting the value to View's property will update the View's property instantly but will not animate it

So finally, if you want to animate the change in the value of view's property you will have to use UIView.animate as shown below.

```
let view = MyView()

 UIView.animate(withDuration: 10) {
     view.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
     view.mySublayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
 }
```

Hope it helps